# VPS Adon Domains vs Individual Cpanel

Tags: cpanel, vps, whm

I have 10 websites on a VPS.  Should each one have its on cPanel or is it better to have 1 cPanel and have 9 adon domains?

Which way uses the least amount of server ram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your customer demands individual cPanel accounts to manage their websites themeselves, seperate cPanel is good option. If you are going to manage all website at your own there is no need to create cPanel accounts.

As far as server RAM usage concerns, when cPanel account will be accessed it will consume the RAM. When cPanel (website) is not in use your VPS RAM wont be utilised. If you never access the other cPanels there wont be any difference in RAM usage whether you go for separate cPanel account or with addon domain option. However, with separate cPanel account option you will have ease of managing domain, websites, DNS, backups etc.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you please create separate cPanel account for your 10 domains so that you can easily find out which user is using high server resources